# ACF Custom Fields WP GraphQL suddenly starts returning null in Gatsby even though it used to work

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Wordpress as a headless CMS to manage content in my Gatsby Site. I used Advanced Custom Fields to create custom fields to easily manage the fields and contents to curate and pull into my Gatsby Application. Everything was working fine till I decided to start my Gatsby Project not long ago and started getting `null` errors. I went to the GraphQL page on Gatsby with this address `localhost:8000/___graphql` to query my data there only to see that all my fields were now returning `null`.

I also visited the remote wordpress page to test the GraphQL IDE but everything works fine there.
I have cleared the cache of my Gatsby Application but I am still getting the same error.

Here is an example of such Query for a custom field called `homePage`

```
query MyQuery {
        wpPage {
          homePage {
            heroSubtitle
            heroTitle
            heroPlaystoreCtaText
            heroImage {
              localFile {
                childImageSharp {
                  gatsbyImageData(width: 614, height: 477, quality: 100, placeholder: BLURRED)
                }
              }
              altText
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

All these fields are returning null even though they were all working 7 hours ago. The most baffling thing is that the same exact query works when I decided to query through `allWpPage` and `nodes`. Why is it working here and NOT working on specific `WpPage` query. The first node result returns empty but the second node returns the correct data. Why did it suddenly stop working?

```
query MyQuery {
  allWpPage {
    nodes {
      homePage {
        heroSubtitle
        heroTitle
        heroPlaystoreCtaText
        heroImage {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(width: 614, height: 477, quality: 100, placeholder: BLURRED)
            }
          }
          altText
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the reason it wasn't working was because I added a new page which moved down the home page and caused it to always return null. I modified my query to general `wpPages` query and filtered by `/`(Home Page) which brought out the specific results for Home Page. Here is the Query I used now:

```
query HeroQuery {
        hero: allWpPage(filter: {uri: {eq: "/"}}) {
          edges {
            node {
              homePage {
                heroSubtitle
                heroTitle
                heroPlaystoreCtaText
                heroImage {
                  localFile {
                    childImageSharp {
                      gatsbyImageData(width: 614, height: 477, quality: 100, placeholder: BLURRED)
                    }
                  }
                  altText
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```